# Issue with OpenCV 3.10 installation on Windows 7

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm total begginer in Cmake and I don't know where I have to put code. My problem is:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:81 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0020 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
```

I'm following the instructions here https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/

and found the answer here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/165060/opencv-32-install-problems-in-windows10-64-bit-vs2017/

I need to add line in Cmake file but I don't know where to add it.

```
cmake -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```

If I add it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UIWc.jpg it shows me error: CMake Error at

```
CMakeLists.txt:12:
Parse error. Expected a command name, got left paren with text "(".
```

this is my cmake file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rhT_Sl2XH-ejI_tDBfSIbl2304huDq3n

Using Visual Studio 2013, OpenCV 3.10 Cmake 3.12

Can anyone help me?

edited:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication14, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::get(int)const " (?get@VideoCapture@cv@@UEBANH@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::isOpened(void)const " (?isOpened@VideoCapture@cv@@UEBA_NXZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(void)" (??1VideoCapture@cv@@UEAA@XZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QEAA@H@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::write(class cv::Mat const &)" (?write@VideoWriter@cv@@UEAAXAEBVMat@2@@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::~VideoWriter(void)" (??1VideoWriter@cv@@UEAA@XZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::VideoWriter(class cv::String const &,int,double,class cv::Size_<int>,bool)" (??0VideoWriter@cv@@QEAA@AEBVString@1@HNV?$Size_@H@1@_N@Z)
1>c:\users\vartotojas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication14\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication14.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

errors with opencv_videoio300.lib:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication14, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.cpp(15): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>Source.cpp(16): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ICOpen
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ICClose
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ICSendMessage
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ICDecompress
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIFileInit
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIFileRelease
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIFileOpenA
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIFileGetStream
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIFileCreateStreamA
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamRelease
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamInfoA
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamSetFormat
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamWrite
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamGetFrameOpen
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamGetFrame
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIStreamGetFrameClose
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVIMakeCompressedStream
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AVISaveOptions
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol capCreateCaptureWindowA
1>opencv_videoio300.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol capGetDriverDescriptionA
1>c:\users\vartotojas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication14\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication14.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This is a good tutorial to build OpenCV from source on Windows: https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/

Comment: `CMake Deprecation Warning` is definitely not **your** problem. Firstly, it is not an *error* but just a **warning**, so doesn't prevent building the project. Secondly, it explains that some line of code is correct, but it is better to avoid it. As the code isn't yours, nothing bad for you.

Comment: The line `cmake -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` tells you that you need to set `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` **configuration parameter** to `OFF`. If you call `cmake` for configure the project, then given configuration parameter should be set with `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` option (look into original line!). If you use CMake GUI, then you should set parameter in the parameters area of that GUI. (You should hit "Configure" for fill up the area with parameters for being able to change them).

Comment: There is [no such thing](https://opencv.org/releases.html) as OpenCV **3.10**...

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. I'll probably try to use exactly the same versions as in tutorial because now I'm getting `C:\Users\Vartotojas>cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
Error: could not load cache`

Comment: Actually unchecking ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS didn't work for me, I just deleted lines of warnings in cmakelists showed in the error and on configuration I also got bunch of warnings

Comment: the same Error: could not load cache in 3.3.1 I probably need to try other tutorials but at least got no errors on configuring and building

Comment: @jodis Thanks I did everything successfully, but one weird thing that I got libraries with 400.lib endings.

Comment: Just exposed another problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624448/opencv-3-error-cv-fourcc-identifier-not-found) But this code is working on All-in-one version of OpenCV

Comment: where did you get your source? the latest [release](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) is 3.4.2

Comment: @jodis [here](https://imgur.com/a/dVzCQPB)

Comment: I think I have to do again with normal source OMG. At least it's probably good tutorial I think

Comment: yeah, that's a bit confusing the first time. you should download it from the release page. It might not work properly otherwise.

Comment: @jodis Thanks, it's working. I built static libraries too but if I add all libs to Linker>Input, I'm getting error of library: opencv_videoio300.lib. If I remove it from Input I'm getting bunch of errors. See edited. Do you maybe know a way how to get it working with static libraries? P.S. I built static libraries by uncheking BUILD_SHARED_LIBS in Cmake GUI.

Comment: Also added errors with opencv_videoio300.lib

Comment: Yeah!!! Added vfw32.lib and it's working. [Solved]